# Group overlapping intervals

Tags: algorithms

Given a number of intervals:

```
--   (1, 3) a
 -   (2, 3) b
 --  (2, 4) c
  -- (3, 5) d
```

```
intervals = [(1, 3), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 5)]
```

I would like to generate the minimum number of groups so that in each group any 2 intervals overlap.

```
[a, b, c]
[c, d]
```

Please note that (1, 3) and (3, 5) are not considered overlapping intervals, so it is similar but not quite a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962015/given-a-set-of-intervals-find-the-minimum-number-of-points-that-need-to-be-plac

Is there any efficient or not so efficient way to do this?

I guess I could just generate a set of overlapping intervals for each interval and then delete duplicated sets.

Edit: also not quite the same as calculating components from a graph, as an interval can be in more than 1 group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a graph as follows:

- each vertex is one of the intervals
- two vertices are connected by an edge if their intervals overlap.

Now the problem you stated is equivalent to finding all [cliques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)) in an undirected graph, which is a pretty tough problem, since it is NP-hard. You may be able to find some pointers to algorithms which give you a suboptimal solution, but don't expect too much.

Comment: Seems like the correct approach! I will study if it is worth to implement this or just delete duplicated sets. Thank you very much!